# Retrieve file from S3 with curl from EC2 using IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I created an IAM role and assigned it to my EC2 instance. I created an IAM role policy and linked it to my S3 bucket. I can now list the files on my S3 bucket using the `aws-cli` on my EC2 instance.

```
[root@ec2.hostname.aws.com ~]# aws --region eu-west-1 s3 ls s3://s3-bucket-name
2017-05-02 02:37:39        137 index.html
```

Now if I try to `curl` that file I get an access denied error:

```
[root@ec2.hostname.aws.com ~]# curl https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-name/index.html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>782176F442A4995A</RequestId><HostId>qZWZTXZdlgtD4BiVYfp5+Mj/gU3UXRiYQmsSyaAhwED1JtzUWs9QKE99RmsQ6w0uDB
```

Is there a way I could make this `curl` request work without relaxing the permissions on the S3 bucket? Something like authentication, headers etc etc.

Comment: ``curl `aws --region eu-west-1 s3 presign s3://s3-bucket-name/index.html` ``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GET requests to Amazon S3 require an **authorization string** that uses [AWS Signature v4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html).

See: [GET Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html)

Alternatively, you could create a [Pre-Signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) which has extra parameters and grants time-limited access to an Amazon S3 object. You can generate a Pre-Signed URL with a couple of lines of code and then provide it to users (or use it in an HTML page) to grant temporary access to private objects stored in Amazon S3.

Of course, the easiest way to retrieve data from Amazon S3 is by using API calls or the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Comment: Presigned url is a great strategy, especially if you're using a library that doesn't let you add headers to the curl command.